# Siyum of Bava Kama/Metzia/Basra or Sanhedrin/Makkos

Tags: siyum, maseches-sanhedrin, bava-metzia, bava-kamma

I have been told that originally, Bava Kama, Bava Metzia and Bava Basra were one masechta called Maseches Nezikin and that Makkos was part of Maseches Sanhedrin. A siyum of a masechta of Gemora is apparently a Seudas Mitzvah, which is why it can according to most opinions circumvent the prohibition of eating meat and drinking wine during the nine days and also let a bechor (firstborn) not have to fast. If there is a siyum of one of these "Masechtos" (i.e. one or two of the Bavas or only Makkos or Sanhedrin but not both) is it considered a seudas mitzvah?

Comment: http://www.torahmusings.com/2011/08/a-siyum-for-a-daf/

Comment: FWIW, while those masekhtes were originally combined in the Mishna, they have **always** been discrete masekhtes in the gemara.

Comment: FYI, "Maseches Nezikin" (the three Bava's) is discussed in AZ 7a. I believe you're referring to Makkos 2a with Makkos being attached to Sanhedrin at some point, but that sounds like a misreading of that Gemara. All that means is that the previous Mishnah in Shas discussed half-Ka'asher Zamam and thus we now present a Mishnah of no Ka'asher Zamam. No proof that the two masechtos were originally one. And if you want to fit that into those words, you'd have to say the same about Makkos to Shavuos as well.

Comment: Also, the Maharsha is of the opinion that all of Seder Nezikin was one Masechta (BB 2a).