# Issur of Playing Cards

Tags: halacha, games-toys

Is there an Issur of playing cards? I'm not asking about gambling, or Shabbos, I'm specifically asking if it is Assur to play a game of cards with playing cards that we have today. Are there specific Poskim who permit or forbid it?

This is not like this [other question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/60641/11501) because I'm not asking about gambling.

Comment: If not gambling or shabbos what is left? Bittul Torah? Meishev Leitzim? Are those card specific?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Halachic permissibility of playing cards (i.e., poker) for money](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/60641/halachic-permissibility-of-playing-cards-i-e-poker-for-money)

Comment: קרטן = שטן.....

Comment: R. Levi Yitzchak of Berditchov (_Kedushat Levi, Chanukah - "Yadua"_) strongly discouraged playing cards because he believed the images on them were associated with bad _klipot_.

Comment: See Nitei Gavriel Hilchos Chanuka 51:24 with footnotes

Comment: @sam I've heard of that explanation I believe it also has roots in Kedushas Levi, no?

Answer (score 5):

The [Taamei Haminhagim](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=14556#p=379&fitMode=fitheight&hlts=&ocr=) (849) quotes the Bnei Yissas'char that cards represent the Greek's impure spirit resting on the 36 cards, which parallel the 36 tractates in Shas.

It also said in the footnote that there was a Cherem against card-playing, with the explicit exception that it doesn't apply on Chanuka. And that exception was only to help quiet the evil inclination (So you don't have to stop cold-turkey, you can still play once a year...)

Comment: I thought there were 37 tractates of Talmud - but maybe there are different ways of counting

Comment: @mbloch https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/88822/759

Comment: Some decks had 36 cards (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_playing_cards)) and he's probably referring to the deck he was most familiar with

Comment: @ba Thanks for the info. I was sitting here thinking, "but I thought card decks had 52 cards..."